# how do I host my app on a github page gh-pages?

Tags: git, github

I have the following setup of an app I am working on, and I would like to host the app on github using gh-pages. here I hope to achieve this.

```
UserName@PC1 ~/GitHub/ud989-retain
$ ls
css  index.html  js

UserName@PC1 ~/GitHub/ud989-retain
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

UserName@PC1 ~/GitHub/ud989-retain
$ git branch
* master
```

below is what I do to get my page hosted on gihub gh-pages

```
# create the gh-pages branch
git branch gh-pages   

# think this copies all files from master/origin to gh-pates(remotely and locally I think?)
git push origin gh-pages

# this shows the branches available(master and gh-pages and you should be on master)
git branch

# change to the gh-pages branch
git checkout gh-pages

#get the status of your repo, it should be upto date 
git status

# this shows the branches available(master and gh-pages and you should be on gh-pages)
git branch

# create a .nojekyll, not sure what this does exactly but it is required 
touch .nojekyll

# you should be able to see your .nojekyll
ls -a

# now add your .nojekyll for committing, not sure why i don't have to commit the others but maybe they are done with the git push origin gh-pages
git add .nojekyll

# commit the file with a comment 
git commit -a -m "adding .nojekyll file"

# this gives the remote URLs, not required but just checking they are there
git remote -v

# push to your remote repo, and I should be able to view my page online 
git push origin gh-pages
```

So the end result will be 2 branches in your github account, master and gh-pages and they should have the same files. Then you should get a link to where your page is hosted.This can be found in the settings of your git hub account.

**EDIT1** Once the above is done if you go yo your github page with your repo and select settings, under Gihub pages you should have for example: GitHub Pages
 Your site is published at http://hattricknz.github.io/ud989-retain.

**NOTE** I have searched various places for this, but I cannot find it document too well, or I always run into problems. 
So here I hope this to be a good reference to me. Also there could be other/better ways of doing something similar that I am not aware of.

---

### EDIT2

Just revisiting this:
I have a repo that I just pushed to github with a master branch that looks something like:

```
$ ls
assets  index.html  README.md  robots.txt
```

Now I want to publish it on github.
I was about to follow this from my notes

```
git branch gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages
git branch
git checkout gh-pages
git status
git branch
touch .nojekyll
ls -a
git add .nojekyll
git commit -a -m "adding .nojekyll file"
git remote -v
git push origin gh-pages
```

But I just done the following: and went to settings of my repo and it said `Your site is published at ...`. so maybe this is all I need to do? I will revisit again...

```
git branch gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages
git branch
git checkout gh-pages
```

Comment: your page is working fine, than what's the issue? you cannot host your app in `gh-pages`. you can host (i mean source copy) in master and `gh-pages` is for documentation. Either you have some misconception or I didn't get your question.

Comment: it was more a confirmation than a question, and it will act a reference for me. am i correct to say master has all the files, including documentation(e.g. README.md) and gh-pages is the files that will be used for the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [**`gh-pages`**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/), it gives step by step documentation

```
git clone repo.git
cd repo
git branch --orphan gh-pages
```

add your html/css/js files ...than commit and push.

```
git push origin gh-pages
```

Comment: have looked at that before but always get lost or it dosen't work. and have the following questions: why for the following: that does not use a `.nojekyll` file. it creates an orphan without any parents. it just adds a basic index.html file, what about in my case where it has other files .js .css.

Comment: you can add `css`, `js` and what ever you want to add, `.nojekyll` for disable `jekyll` blog engine, which is maybe default in github now

Comment: why does it suggest this `# Remove all files from the old working tree` and what is the old working tree

Comment: I have no idea where did you get this script and the question you asked

Comment: its in the gh-pages link you gave `git rm -rf .
# Remove all files from the old working tree
rm '.gitignore'`

Comment: should this `git branch --orphan gh-pages` not read like this `git checkout --orphan gh-pages`